# How do I properly define an example for a nullable property in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI and openapi-generator-maven-plugin with Spring Boot. I'm trying to create an example object in my response. I've followed the suggestions of several different web pages, especially this one:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/

But no matter what I try, I can't get the example data to show up correctly.
Here the object that should be in a request:

```
Period:
  type: object
  required:
    - startDate
    - endDate
  properties:
    startDate:
      type: string
      format: date
      nullable: true
      example: "2021-01-01"
    endDate:
      type: string
      format: date
      nullable: true
      example: "2030-01-01"

CreateInstancesRequest:
  type: object
  required:
    - id
  properties:
    id:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Id'
    period:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Period'
```

But I get not what I want:

[image]

I expect something like this:

```
{
  "id": "some-id",
  "period": {
    "endDate": "2020-01-01",
    "startDate": "2022-01-01"
  }
}
```

But maybe I am wrong because generated java code for the Period class:
[image]

I think `present` property from actual example came from `org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable` class.

Jackson's object mapper configured like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
objectMapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You're not including `jackson-datatype-jdk8` properly.

Comment: I don't think including `jackson-datatype-jdk8` will help. Edited question.